# Reference instance when MainWindow is not the startup window

Tags: c#, xaml

I am doing some application for college and I have successfully been able to show and collapse usercontrols in my application, but when the window I am trying to do it is not the one that starts when the application starts, it just doesn't work.

I have a mouse event that works when I click on one of the labels (acting as a menu):

```
class MouseEvents
    {        public void MouseClick(object sender)
        {
            //creating an instance of MainWindow to be able to reference the labels and user controls
            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            List<Label> menuDown = new List<Label> { mainWindow.toolAddPlayer, mainWindow.toolSearchPlayer, mainWindow.toolAddMember, mainWindow.toolSearchMember, mainWindow.toolEditPass, mainWindow.toolEmailList };
            List<UserControl> userDown = new List<UserControl> { mainWindow.addPlayer, mainWindow.searchPlayer, mainWindow.addMember, mainWindow.searchMember, mainWindow.editPassword, mainWindow.EmailList };
            var menuItem = (Label)sender;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (menuItem.Content == menuDown[i].Content)
                {
                    HideUserControls();
                    userDown[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }

        public void HideUserControls()
        {
            MainWindow usingControls = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            usingControls.addPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            usingControls.searchPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            usingControls.addMember.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            usingControls.searchMember.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            usingControls.editPassword.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            usingControls.EmailList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

On the window xaml (MainWindow.xaml) where I want my usercontrols to appear or disappear, I have this code

```
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="440" Width="590">
            <local:AddPlayer x:Name="addPlayer" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:SearchPlayer x:Name="searchPlayer" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:AddMember x:Name="addMember" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:SearchMember x:Name="searchMember" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:EditPassword x:Name="editPassword" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <local:EmailList x:Name="EmailList" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

And it works perfectly. The problem is when I want to add a window to log in the application (this LogIn window will then load the MainWindow.xaml when I click the LogIn button). I changed my App.xaml to update the StartupUri to LogIn.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SimplyRugby_2._0.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimplyRugby_2._0"
             StartupUri="LogIn.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

So the application starts as it should, on the LogIn window. The problem comes when I try to click on the menu on the MainWindow window.

I get a reference not to an instance of an object error. I have been checking around on StackOverflow and google but I really cannot seem to find the solution. I don't know how to reference it. I did it when MainWindow was the window that starts when I initialize the app, but if it is not the first window, it just gives me the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

mainWindow was null.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I highly recommend you have a look into "MVVM in WPF" and use ViewModels, Commands and Bindings. It will definitely relieve you of those headaches.

Comment: If you decide to first try and figure this out then this may be of interest to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow?view=netframework-4.8 (Note the examples section, where a MainWindow is explicitly set)

Comment: Thank you Fildor. I will check that out. I always see people referencing MVVM but I have never looked into it. I actually managed to fix my problem without it, and I will put the solution. I know it was probably a silly mistake, but starting to code can be a headache sometimes haha.

Comment: Well, it has quite a learning curve, but once you get used to it, you'll appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much again Fildor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem and the solution, so I will post it here just in case somebody has a similar problem.

My main problem was that I couldn't understand why it was working when the window was the startup window, but not when it wasn't. I just had to an instance of the MainWindow (which is not the startup window).

```
    class MouseEvents
    {      
        private MainWindow WindowMain { get; set; }

        public MouseEvents(MainWindow window)
        {
            this.WindowMain = window;
        }
        public void MouseClick(object sender)
        {
            List<Label> menuDown = new List<Label> { WindowMain.toolAddPlayer, WindowMain.toolSearchPlayer, WindowMain.toolAddMember, WindowMain.toolSearchMember, WindowMain.toolEditPass, WindowMain.toolEmailList };
            List<UserControl> userDown = new List<UserControl> { WindowMain.addPlayer, WindowMain.searchPlayer, WindowMain.addMember, WindowMain.searchMember, WindowMain.editPassword, WindowMain.emailList };
            Label menuItem = (Label)sender;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (menuItem.Content == menuDown[i].Content)
                {
                    HideUserControls();
                    userDown[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }

        public void HideUserControls()
        {
            WindowMain.addPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WindowMain.searchPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WindowMain.addMember.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WindowMain.searchMember.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WindowMain.editPassword.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WindowMain.emailList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

And then update the method from the MainWindow that calls the MouseClick event on the MouseEvent class.

```
        private void LeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseEvents menu = new MouseEvents(this);
            menu.MouseClick(sender);
        }
```